# Grammaticalization of third person singular -s in English

Tags: morphology, language-change, inflection, grammaticalisation

Is there any evidence that the third person singular -s can be traced back to a lexical item before it became an inflection? I am trying to see if the theory of grammaticalization applies to its diachronic process. The cline of grammaticalization is as follows:

Lexical item > grammatical word > clitic > inflectional affix.

Comment: I could have sworn I commented on this question. Strange.

Comment: I have seen this as PIE _*-ti_ -> PGmc _*-di/*-ði_ -> AS _-t/-ð/-þ_ -> ME _-th_ (Southern)/ _-s_ (Northern) -> ModE _-s_. The Northern _-s_ came from the influence of Norse mediopassive _-sk_; eventually the Northern usage became standard in Modern English. According to this, the form has been inflectional at least back to late PIE.

Comment: Oh, it was on English.SE also. That should have been noted. I will make this an answer.

Comment: Yes, someone suggested I post it here too. Thanks for your response in both !

Answer (score 6):

PIE **-ti* -> PGmc **-di/-ði* -> AS -*t/-ð/-þ* -> ME *-th* (Southern)/ *-s* (Northern) -> ModE *-s*

The Northern *-s* came from the influence of Norse mediopassive *-sk*; eventually the Northern usage became standard in Modern English. According to this, the form has been inflectional at least back to late PIE.